# Installing Rave Reports in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi-xe4, rave-reports

I have an application which was developed in Delphi XE.
Now I try to run this on Delphi XE4 but I get compilation errors that RpDefine,RpBase,RpSystem are missing
I have googled and found out that these come with Rave Reports

How do I install Rave Reports for Delphi XE4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy Nevrona RAVE XE4 version and install that:

http://www.nevrona.com/reg/

http://www.nevrona.com/order/index.html

Comment: Have you been using it yourself? Any alternatives?